# How to create a rank k matrix using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

Im looking to create a matrix of rank `k`.
The dimension of the matrix is `m x n`. The input `k` satisfies that condition that `k < min(m,n)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a trivial method is to produce a matrix that looks like:

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

i.e. *k* columns of the identity matrix, then repeat the last column *n-k* times (or *m-k* times, depending on orientation).

Answer (score 4):

It's not really so clear what you are aiming for.

But in order to create a matrix `B` with specific rank `k`, from a matrix `A` (with `rank` at least `k`), you may like to utilize `svd` and proceed like:

```
>>> A= rand(7, 5);
>>> rank(A)
ans =  5
>>> [U, S, V]= svd(A);
>>> k= 3;
>>> B= U(:, 1: k)* S(1: k, 1: k)* V(:, 1: k)';
>>> rank(B)
ans =  3
```

Answer (score 1):

A matrix of rank 1 can be created by the outer product of two vectors, for example:

```
A = randn(10,1) * randn(1,10);
```

Add together k of these and you will have a matrix of rank k. Like this:

```
>> A = zeros(10);
>> for i = 1:4, A = A + randn(10,1) * randn(1,10); end
>> rank(A)

ans =  4
```

Comment: to be precise, your method produces a matrix of rank <= k. It might be the case where two random vectors would be linearly dependent (not very likely, but possible, especially if k is close to m or n)

Comment: while you're at it, it can be done without the loop `A = rand(m, k)*rand(k,n); rank(A)`