# From expensive search to Integer Programming or Constraint Programming?

Tags: math, constraint-programming, integer-programming

Consider m by n matrices M, all of whose entries are 0 or 1.  For a given M, the question is whether there exists a non zero vector v, all of whose entries are -1, 0 or 1 for which Mv = 0. For example,

```
      [0 1 1 1]
M_1 = [1 0 1 1]
      [1 1 0 1]
```

In this example, there is no such vector v.

```
      [1 0 0 0]
M_2 = [0 1 0 0]
      [0 0 1 0]
```

In this example, the vector (0,0,0,1) gives M_2v = 0.

Given an m and n, I would like to find if there exists such an M so that there is no non-zero v such that Mv = 0.

If `m = 3` and `n = 4` then the answer is *yes* as we can see above.

I am currently solving this problem by trying all different M and v which is very expensive.

> However, is it possible to express the problem as an integer
>   programming problem or constraint programming problem so I can use an
>   existing software package, such as SCIP instead which might be more
>   efficient.

Comment: Isn't the answer always `yes` ? If I understood the question properly, any matrix with a column having elements set to zero will fit the answer. And this is valid for any `m` and `n`.

Comment: @rpsml No, the matrix `M` might be square and regular, and the problem demands for a vector with _nonzero_ entries. It is necessary to check whether `M` has a nontrivial Kernel which contains a nonzero vector having entries from `{0,1,-1}`.

Comment: @rpsml I think you might have misread the question.  I would like to find if there exists such an M so that there is **no** non-zero v such that Mv = 0.

Comment: @Codor and @user2179021: I think I still do not get the question. If the question is: "is there a pair `M` (size `m x n`) and `v` (size `n`) so that `M v = 0` if `v` is not `0` (and I am adding and if `M` is not `0 ` either) ?  For this question the answer is yes. Basically the example in the question can be generalized to any size `m x n`: take any matrix `M` and set its last column to `0` (all other elements can be random `0's` and `1's`). Take a vector `v^t = ( 0 0 0 0 ... 1 )`. This vector is non-zero and its product with `M` is a null vector. What is the flaw in my construction ?

Comment: @rpsml Sorry for the confusion. The question is, is there an M such that there **does not exist a non-zero v** such that Mv = 0.  Is there some way we can chat live on stackoverflow?

Comment: @rpsml to be a little clear. The question *is not* the one you stated.

Comment: @dorothy I stand corrected. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @dorothy To answer the question in part: If `m = n`, if `M` is the unit matrix of dimension `m` times `m`, `Mv=0` is true if and only if `v` is the zero vector, which means that the answer to the problem is *yes* for the case `m = n`.

Comment: @Codor Thank you. You are right the identity matrix solves it for a square matrix with a yes.  It's trickier when `m < n` however .

Comment: @dorothy I believe that for the case `m < n` (where `M` cannot have full rank and hence a kernel of nonzero dimension), one could use Gaussian elimination or elementary row operations to transform `M` into an upper diagonal matrix, chose `v` in such a way that it is zero except for a position of the missing step in the transformed `M` and apply to `v` the inverses of the elementary row operations. If I'm not mistaken, one would arrive at a `v'` with all zeros and a single entry `1` or `-1`; the `-1` would be okay since `-v` would also be contained in the kernel of `M`.

Comment: @Codor M_1 in the question must be a counter example to this if what you are saying is that the answer is always no.

Comment: @user2179021 No, my idea is wrong. `M_1` has rank `3` which means that the kernel has dimension `1`. Applying gaussian elimination yields that `{(1,1,1,-2)}` is a basis of the kernel, however the vector `(1,1,1,-2)` is apparently linearly independent from any vector with entries in `{0,1,-1}`.

Comment: For `n = m+1` and `m >= 3`, the matrix `M_1` nicely generalizes: the matrix with all `1` except on the diagonal is such a matrix. The kernel of that matrix is the 1-dimensional space of multiples of `(1,1,1,...,1,1-m)`, which does not contain any vector made of just `{0,1,-1}`.

Comment: Also, if the answer is "yes" for `(m,n)`, then it is "yes" for `(m+k,n)` for any positive integer `k`: just repeat any of the rows of the `M` that works for `(m,n)`. As a consequence, you're really searching, for each `n`, what is the minimal `m` such that the answer for `(m,n)` is "yes". Also, in the exhaustive search, you can skip any matrix with two equal rows since if that worked that would mean the answer was "yes" for an even smaller `m`. Since you can shuffle the rows as well, you can then assume that the rows are strictly increasing.

Answer (score 6):

This question is probably more mathematical than progamming. I haven't found the final answer yet, but at least some ideas are here:

We can re-state the problem in the following way.

> Problem A: Fix positive integers `m` and `n`. Let `S` be the set of `n`-dimensional vectors whose entries are `0` or `1`. Does there exist any `m` by `n` matrix `M` whose entries are `0` or `1`, such that, for any two different vectors `v_1` and `v_2` in `S`, the vectors `Mv_1` and `Mv_2` are different. (Or, you may say that, the matrix `M`, considered as an application from `n`-dimensional vectors to `m`-dimensional vectors, is injective on the set `S`.)

In brief: *given the pair `(m, n)`, does there exist such an injective `M`?*

Problem A is equivalent to the original problem. Indeed, if `Mv_1 = Mv_2` for two different `v_1` and `v_2` in `S`, then we have `M(v_1 - v_2) = 0`, and the vector `v_1 - v_2` will have only `0`, `1`, `- 1` as entries. The inverse is obviously also true.

Another reinterpretation is:

> Problem B: Let `m`, `n` be a positive integer and `S` be the set of `n`-dimensional vectors whose entries are `0` and `1`. Can we find `m` vectors `r_1, ..., r_m` in `S`, such that, for any pair of different vectors `v_1` and `v_2` in `S`, there exists an `r_i`, which satisfies `<v_1, r_i> != <v_2, r_i>`? Here `<x, y>` is the usual inner product.

In brief: *can we choose `m` vectors in `S` to distinguish everyone in `S` by taking inner product with the chosen ones?*

Problem B is equivalent to Problem A, because you can identify the matrix `M` with `m` vectors in `S`.

In the following, I will use both descriptions of the problem freely.

Let's call the pair `(m, n)` a "**good pair**" if the answer to Problem A (or B) is **yes**.

With the description of Problem B, it is clear that, for a given `n`, there is a minimal `m` such that `(m, n)` is a good pair. Let us write `m(n)` for this minimal `m` associated to `n`.

Similarly, for a given `m`, there is a maximal `n` such that `(m, n)` is good. This is because, if `(m, n)` is good, i.e. there is an injective `M` as stated in Problem A, then for any `n' <= n`, erasing any `n - n'` columns of `M` will give an injective `M'`. Let us write `n(m)` for this maximal `n` associated to `m`.

So the task becomes to calculate the functions `m(n)` and/or `n(m)`.

We first prove several lemmas:

> Lemma 1: We have `m(n + k) <= m(n) + m(k)`.

Proof: If `M` is an `m(n)` by `n` injective matrix for the pair `(m(n), n)` and `K` is an `m(k)` by `k` injective matrix for the pair `(m(k), k)`, then the `(m(n) + n(k))` by `(n + k)` matrix

```
[M 0]
[0 K]
```

works for the pair `(m(n) + 1, n + 1)`. To see this, let `v_1` and `v_2` be any pair of different `(n + k)`-dimensional vectors. We may cut both of them into two pieces: the first `n` entries, and the last `k` entries. If the first pieces of them are not equal, then they can be distinguished by one of the first `m(n)` rows of the above matrix; if the first pieces of them are equal, then the second pieces of them must be different, hence they can be distinguished by one of the last `m(k)` rows of the above matrix.

> Remark: The sequence `m(n)` is thus a [subadditive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity) sequence.

A simple corollary:

> Corollary 2: We have `m(n + 1) <= m(n) + 1`, hence `m(n) <= n`.

Proof: Take `k = 1` in Lemma 1.

Note that, from other known values of `m(n)` you can get better upper bounds. For example, since we know that `m(4) <= 3`, we have `m(4n) <= 3n`. Anyway, these always give you `O(n)` upper bounds.

The next lemma gives you a lower bound.

> Lemma 3: `m(n) >= n / log2(n + 1)`.

Proof: Let `T` be the set of `m(n)`-dimensional vectors whose entries lie in `{0, 1, ..., n}`. Any `m(n)` by `n` matrix `M` gives a map from `S` to `T`, sending `v` to `Mv`.

Since there exists an `M` such that the above map is injective, then necessarily the size of the set `T` is at least the size of the set `S`. The size of `T` is `(n + 1)^m`, and the size of `S` is `2^n`, thus we have:

`(n + 1)^m(n) >= 2^n`

or equivalently, `m(n) >= n / log2(n + 1)`.

### Back to programming

I have to say that I haven't figured out a good algorithm.
You might restate the problem as a [Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), as follows:

Let `U` be the set of `n` dimensional vectors with entries `1`, `0` or `- 1`, and let `S` be as above. Every vector `w` in `S` gives a subset `C_w` of `U`: `C_w = {v in U: <w, v> != 0}`. The question is then: can we find `m` vectors `w` such that the union of the subsets `C_w` is equal to `U`.

The general Set Cover Problem is NP complete, but in the above Wiki link there is an integer linear program formulation.

Anyway, this cannot take you much further than `n = 10`, I guess.

I'll keep editting this answer if I have further results.

Comment: A set cover reduction is potentially interesting how large would an instance be?

Comment: As I explained, you will have a set `U` of size `3^n`, and `2^n` subsets of `U`. The task is to find a covering of `U` with minimal number of subsets. But the time cost is still expensive. What are the values of `(m, n)` that you are interested in?

Comment: Ah.. An instance of set cover of size 3^n is not good.  n = 50 and m = 25 is an interesting set of parameters.

Comment: Well ... yes, as I said it's not very helpful. I will think about your particular pair `(25, 50)` later. Perhaps this case is attackable with some ugly optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

i think using Boolean matrix multiplication will allow you to solve the Mv=0 problem with only 1's & 0's more efficiently. Using this method you should be able to solve without worrying about rank deficiencies due to the RHS equaling zero. Here is a link to documentation on some algorithms for using BMM:

http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/cs367/lecture2.pdf

Comment: I am not sure how this addresses the question. The problem is this: Given an m and n,  I would like to find if there exists such an M so that there is no non-zero v such that Mv = 0.  How does your answer solves this problem?

Comment: while it does not give you the exact code to solve your problem it shows how to take advantage of the Boolean nature of your data to perform the Ax=0 problem that you have. Without constraining the problem to this set, the solution becomes poorly conditioned since in order to solve for x, A must be divided by zeros. Using boolean matrix algebra seems like a good way around this issue

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you are asking for a given m,n if there exists a Matrix M, (Linear Transformation), with a trivial kernal, that is Ker(M)={0}.

Recall that this is the same as the Nullspace of M being zero 0, Null(M)=0.

For the system Mv=0 the nullspace is {0} if the rank of the matrix M is equal to the dimension of v. So your question comes down to asking about the existence of a mxn matrix with rank dim(v)=m.
The problem in this form has been discussed here

[Generate "random" matrix of certain rank over a fixed set of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132585/generate-random-matrix-of-certain-rank-over-a-fixed-set-of-elements)

You can also frame this question in terms of determinants because if M has determinant=0 then the nullspace is nontrivial. So you can think about this question in terms of constucting a matrix with entries in {-1,0,1} with a desired determinant.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No that's not quite it. The kernel isn't allowed to contain any non-zero vectors whose elements are -1, 0, 1. It  could contain other vectors and in fact is guaranteed to if the elements are allowed to vary over the reals the matrix is non-square.

Comment: Ah, I misread the problem. I thought entries in both the matrix and the vector v were from {0,1,-1}, and hence you were working over the vector space over {0,1,-1}. My apologies.

Comment: Besides, there's no such a thing as "vector space over {0, 1, - 1}"... the set is not a field.

Comment: @whatUip, You are absolutely right, I am an idiot. For some reason I was thinking of F_3 and did not check to see if what was thinking made sense. But clearly it is not a group with respect to +. I will bow out in shame.